# How to set weight and height in Css with responsive when reduce screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to set weight and height in Css and I want them to responsive when reduce screen size  , for now I using php resize before store I just thinking about using html and css or javascript . Is thier anyway to do something like this ?

for example

```
a.jpg ( 500*500 )
```

in html

```
<img src="a.jpg" style="height:200px;width200px;"> // and It will resize when I reduce screen or open it into mobile
```

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. As it stands, you are not asking a specific question that will return a specific answer making your question far too broad.

Comment: @user8663822 200px image width only when full screen or when the width of the browser is at least 200px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use css

max-width: 200px; width: 100%; height: auto;

Comment: If my real image 700* 700 px and I want to display 200*200 Only height should be 200  Is this code height = 700 ? or it will resize ?

Comment: it will be resize to 200

Answer (score 2):

Simply define the image as a percent of its parent. Below the image is 40% width of the page and will consequently scale the height accordingly.

```css
img {
  width:40%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" />
```

Comment: iIs their anyway to get exactly 200 * 200px when It fullscreen with real size 500*500

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understood what you mean. `img {width:200px;height:200px}` will set fixed image dimensions, independent of its original size. You can use `@media query` to adjust dimensions according to screen size. It really depends on your design criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use width in px to make a responsive layout or a responsive img use width 100%, and meta tag in head and use meta queries

Comment: can you give me some example please

Comment: hy let me know first that have you ever designed a responsive website

Comment: if not then you have to read a basic chapter in w3 school for css responsive

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use dynamically then please go with percentage.
Like : 20% or 25%.

But width will be assigned in percentage based on parent width as well.
So may be you should have to check parent width as well.